# How to convert $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{5\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{k}{n}\right)$ into an integral?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The question asked is:

> $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\pi}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{5\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{k}{n}\right) = ? $
>
> a) $\dfrac{2\pi}{5} \hspace{3em}$
> b) $\dfrac{5}{2} \hspace{3em}$
> c) $\dfrac{2}{5} \hspace{3em}$
> d) $\dfrac{5\pi}{2}$

The solution is given as:<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYCDu.jpg)</sup>

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\pi}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{5\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{k}{n}\right)  \\
&= \frac{2}{5} \int_{0}^{5\pi/2} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
= \frac{2}{5} \int_{0}^{5\pi/2} \cos x \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{2}{5} \left[ \sin x \right]_{0}^{5\pi/2}
= \frac{2}{5} \left[ \sin\frac{5\pi}{2} - \sin 0 \right] \\
&= \frac{2}{5}\sin\left(2\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)
= \frac{2}{5}\cdot\sin\frac{\pi}{2}
= \frac{2}{5}
\end{align*}

My question is how they got

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\pi}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{5\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{k}{n}\right) = \frac{2}{5} \int_{0}^{5\pi/2} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x. $$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum This is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f( a+ k( \frac{b-a}{n})) = \int_a^b  f(x) dx$$

> $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\pi}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} 
> \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{5\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{k}{n}\right) = ? $$

Taking $f(x) = \sin(x)$,

By direct comparison,

$$ a= \frac{\pi}{2}$$

And,

$$ \frac{ 5 \pi}{2} \frac{k}{n} = \frac{k}{n} (b-a)  $$

Or,

$$  \frac{5 \pi}{2} = b -a$$

Or,

$$  b = 3\pi$$

Hence, this is equal to:

$$\frac{2}{5} \int_0^{3\pi} \sin x = \frac{2}{5}$$

Note: Note I multiplied by $ \frac{2}{5}$ to make it $ \frac{b-a}{n}$ form

---

#### The solution

If instead of taking,

$$ f(x) = \sin(x)$$

You took,

$$ f(x) = \sin( \frac{\pi}{2} + x)$$

Then,

$$ f(a + k \frac{b-a}{n}) = \sin( \frac{\pi}{2} + a +k \frac{b-a}{n} )$$

Compare this with the question,

> $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\pi}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} 
> \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{5\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{k}{n}\right) = ? $$

hence,

$$ a= 0 $$

$$ \frac{5\pi}{2}  = b$$

Comment: What was the downvote for ?